# Подключение Chrome Custom Tabs вместо WebView в приложение

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день! Есть макет приложения (взаимодействует с Веб частью), использовал WebView, но не полностью функционирует веб часть. Как интегрировать, подключить Chrome Custom Tabs? Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Элементарно. Подключаете зависимость

```
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:<supportLibraryVersion>"
```

Открываете нужный линк (Kotlin)

```
val customTabsIntent = CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build()
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(<context>, Uri.parse(<url>))
```

Chrome Custom Tab запустится сверху стека экранов приложения.

Как его настроить визуально под стиль приложения и прочее, подробно описано здесь:
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

**AndroidX update.**
В соответствии вот с этой таблицей, зависимость переехала на `androidx.browser:browser`
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings

Все остальное в силе. На данный момент актуальна версия 1.2.0

```
implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0"
```

Comment: ` Uri url = Uri.parse("https://tut.by");
        val customTabsIntent = CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build();
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(<context>,Uri.parse(<url>));` так?

Comment: сколько пробовал, никак не получается...

Comment: По ссылке есть образец рабочего кода на Java.

Comment: Пришлось взять много из https://github.com/anandwana001/mindorks-cct/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/akshay/mindorks_cct/MainActivity.kt для решения задачи. Можно попробовать и другие мануалы.

Comment: Проект из ответа уже устарел, см. Android Browser Helper: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper.